# C# ProgressBar Freezing

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I'm trying to calculatethe md5 hash of a file and put it in a textBox, I also have a ProgressBar that should keep running while the hash if being calculated, I set the ProgressBar to Marquee, and the bar will run while I select a file but as soon as the hash calculation starts the bar freezes until it is done.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Calcula_MD5_BAR
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;  
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {      
                timer.Start();
                textBox1.Text = GetFileMD5Hash(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                timer.Stop();
                lblTime.Text = timer.Elapsed.ToString();
                progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
                progressBar1.Increment(100);
            }
            progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
        }

        protected string GetFileMD5Hash(string nomeArquivo)
        {
            FileStream file = new FileStream(nomeArquivo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
            file.Close();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: That's entirely normal.  The progress bar cannot repaint, your UI thread is off in the woods doing something else and is not taking care of UI thread duties.  Your user interface is completely frozen, it doesn't respond to input and does not repaint itself.  Use a BackgroundWorker to run the GetFileMD5Hash() method.

Comment: your function `GetFileMD5Hash(openFileDialog1.FileName)` is blocking one. you should run it in another thread

Comment: You need to move the intensive work to a separate thread, that way the UI thread is free to manage the UI. Look into [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do your non-UI work in a non-UI thread.  `await` helps with making the asynchrony of offloading work to another thread and marshaling the result back to the UI thread *much* easier to work with:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;  
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {      
        timer.Start();
        textBox1.Text = await Task.Run(() => 
            GetFileMD5Hash(openFileDialog1.FileName));
        timer.Stop();
        lblTime.Text = timer.Elapsed.ToString();
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
        progressBar1.Increment(100);
    }
    progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a background worker! Complete example can be found here (pasted below!):

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo

Just set the style to marquee

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            public Form1()
            {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);

                    // To report progress from the background worker we need to set this property
                    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                    // This event will be raised on the worker thread when the worker starts
                    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
                    // This event will be raised when we call ReportProgress
                    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            }
            void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    // Start the background worker
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            // On worker thread so do our thing!
            void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                    // Your background task goes here
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
                    {
                            // Report progress to 'UI' thread
                            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                            // Simulate long task
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
            }
            // Back on the 'UI' thread so we can update the progress bar
            void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                    // The progress percentage is a property of e
                    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            }
    }
```